# Accessing a table in Ruby on Rails via relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to build an inventory system for the various servers and apps we have. I have the following tables/Models:

- App (Application)
- Server (Server)
- Environment (Working environment)

and then I also have a join table which holds the information for the server and apps, called "AppServer".

Here is a picture of the ER Diagram (Sorry, I'm new so I can't post pictures yet)

[ER Diagram](http://tinypic.com/r/2v9oimh/7)

The dotted lines between App->Environment and Server->Environment are indirect connections, i.e. going through AppServer.
Not the best ER Diagram but I tried to make it clear.

So now the ruby code I created to connect the various tables is as follows:

App Model:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :servers
  has_one :app_server
  has_one :environment, :through => :app_servers
end
```

Server Model:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps
  has_one :app_server
  has_one :environment, :through => :app_servers
end
```

Environment Model:

```
class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app_server
end
```

AppServer Model:

```
class AppServer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :environment
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :app
end
```

Everything seems ok so far, I can access the 'AppServer' model from 'App' and from 'Server' by using this command in the ruby IRB console:

```
exampleApp.app_server
exampleServer.app_server

irb(main):183:0> exampleApp.app_server
=> #<AppServer app_id: 1, server_id: 1, environment_id: nil>
irb(main):184:0> exampleServer.app_server
=> #<AppServer app_id: 1, server_id: 1, environment_id: nil>
```

The problem is that if I try to see a list of servers or apps for instance by doing

```
irb(main):188:0> exampleServer.apps
```

I get the following error

```
irb(main):188:0> exampleServer.apps
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'apps_servers'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter
.rb:295:in `table_structure'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter
.rb:186:in `columns'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:230:in `columns'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_ma
ny_association.rb:23:in `columns'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/associations/has_and_belongs_to_ma
ny_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1483:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1483:in `block in
collection_reader_method'
    from (irb):188
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in   `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Same thing when I try out

```
irb(main):189:0> exampleApp.servers
```

Funny thing is, I already have a table called 'app_servers', not 'apps_servers', and even when I tried that out I got other errors.
Anyways, now trying out whether the relationship works, I'll let the code speak for itself:

```
irb(main):193:0> exampleServer.app_server.app
=> #<App id: 1, name: "Test App", description: "This is a test applicaiton", status: "Not deployed", created_at: "2011-0
8-05 09:47:53", updated_at: "2011-08-05 09:47:53">
irb(main):194:0> exampleServer.app_server.server
=> #<Server id: 1, name: "Test Server", locationID: nil, osID: nil, type: nil, comments: "This is just a testing server", 
costCentreID: nil, serverStartDate: nil, serverDecommissionDate: nil, created_at: "2011-08-05 09:50:40", updated_at: "
2011-08-05 09:50:40">
```

So that seems fine, however doing the following will give me a nil answer:

```
irb(main):192:0> exampleServer.app_server.environment
=> nil
irb(main):196:0> exampleApp.app_server.environment
=> nil
```

So trying to link it to an environment model called 'exampleEnvironment' which was instantiated, is also of no use, as the code will show

```
irb(main):006:0> exampleApp.app_server.environment << exampleEnvironment
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

If you guys need any more info (Which I doubt from all this long text[Sorry (^^)]), let me know.

So my questions are, is my relationship wrong or is there something missing from my code?
All I want to be able to do is say

```
exampleServer.apps #Answer will show the linked app
exampleApp.servers #Answer will show the linked server
exampleServer.environment #Answer will show the linked environment through app_server
or
exampleServer.app_Server.environment #Answer will show the linked environment
```

Your help is greatly appreciated, and apologies for this looooooong question.
Thanks in advance d(-_-)b

Comment: I don't see what your question is, sorry

Comment: @bonhoffer my bad, there was a problem with the submission form, so I edited the question again. Should be fine now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted your ER diagram, but it seems that Applications, Servers, and Environments are all independent entities, and an AppServer is a unique combination of one each of the three. The following is based on that assumption.

In this case, AppServer is the join model for the other three models. This relationship in Rails is usually modeled like this:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_servers
  has_many :servers, :through => :app_servers
  has_many :environments, :through => :app_servers
end

class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_servers
  has_many :apps, :through => :app_servers
  has_many :environments, :through => :app_servers
end

class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :app_servers
  has_many :apps, :through => :app_servers
  has_many :servers, :through => :app_servers
end

class AppServer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
  belongs_to :server
  belongs_to :environment
end
```

This should allow you to do all the queries you mentioned in your question.

A good way to decide what kind of relationships to have between your models is to look at which tables will hold the foreign key. Since AppServer holds a `app_id`, for example, it `belongs_to` and App. An App therefore `has_many` or `has_one` AppServer.

Another thing to note is that `has_many :through` is almost always preferred to `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It allows you to explicitly define the join model and make it as flexible as you'd like. In this case, you needed a join model for three tables, so the `has_and_belongs_to_many` default of two tables wouldn't meet your needs.

Comment: Hey, tried out your approach. It does seem to work, in terms of me being able to access environment from server and from the app, however when I check the database now, there doesn't seem to be a way to connect an environment and an application to one server, but rather it creates two different entries. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: With this way of doing it, you need to give much more weight to the join model. A server doesn't directly have apps and environments, it has specific combinations of apps and environments through the AppServer model. This means you don't add apps and environments to servers, you create combinations of the three. For example, it should look more like `AppServer.create(:server => Server.first, :app => App.first, :environment => Environment.first)` than what you've described.

Comment: Tried out what you told me to do:
`AppServer.create(:server => Server.first, :app => App.first, :environment => Environment.first)`
Works as you mentioned, thanks a lot for the help ;-)
But is there another way to do this? Or is this the one and only way to do it?

Comment: No matter how you try to do it, you're going to end up dealing primarily with the `AppServer` objects since they are the glue that holds all of these relationships together. If you want to add an app and an environment to a server like you mentioned, it'll look something like this: `@some_server.app_servers.build(:app => @some_app, :environment => @some_environment)`. You would probably be well served by looking through some of the documenation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at that. But I still don't understand why the database is looking for a table named `App_servers` as opposed to `Apps_server`. Could it be the case only with SQlite? Because I have now changed the database to SQL Server, and when I done `rake db:migrate`, a table called `Apps_servers` was created which caused a lot of problems when trying to access the models via IRB. Had to rename it to `App_servers` and now it works. Any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: This has to do with Rails conventions. When you were using a  `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, there was no explicit join model. Rails assumes there is a simple join table called `apps_servers` (plural joined model names in alphabetical order). Now you have `has_many :though` with an explicit join model. This join model is the same as any another model, so it follows normal model conventions in the database, which is lowercase plural model name with underscores (`AppServer` model => `app_servers` table).

Answer (score 0):

This is for the first problem.

```
irb(main):188:0> exampleServer.apps
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'apps_servers'
```

-You need an intermediate many-to-may table called 'apps_servers' (name is by convention).

-The table will contain two columns with names 'app_id'/integer, 'server_id'/integer. The values of these columns are the primary key value of app row, and server row that is to be linked.

Please lookup Rails guide on many-to-many associations (HABTM).
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your ERD, I think I know the problem.

Rails favors convention over configuration. So, when you tell Rails that your App model

`has_one :app_server`

,it is expected that your **app_server** table has **app_id**. In your ERD, I saw you had **appID** as the field name.

If you try changing the foreign keys in all the tables accordingly, setting, **app_id**, **server_id**, **environment_id**, etc. whenever necessary, I am sure that you will find everything working perfectly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information, but because I used t.reference when creating the AppServer model, it automatically created **app_server** as opposed to what my ERD says.
But thanks for the insight and useful information ;-)